# Registering Zuul on Eureka in Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, netflix-zuul, netflix-eureka, kubectl, netflix-ribbon

I have a Kubernetes cluster on Linux with one master node and two slave nodes. I have installed & created services for a eureka-server and Zuul with multiple replicas which are accessible by NodePorts. In order to enable load balancing, we need to register Zuul service in Eureka.

Can anybody let me know how we can register Zuul on eureka-server?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the configuration for [Zuul Service Discovery](https://github.com/Netflix/zuul/wiki/Core-Features#service-discovery) you can see that there is an option:

```
eureka.serviceUrl.default=http://${region}.${eureka.eurekaServer.domainName}:7001/${eureka.eurekaServer.context}
```

You would have to point that option to your eureka-server [Kubernetes Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/). Based on the [DNS Kubernetes convention](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) it would be something like this:

```
eureka-server-service.<k8s-namespace>.svc.cluster.local:<port-of-service-you-exposed>
```

Comment: Hi Rico, I suppose the command you suggested need to have DNS enabled. I have not enabled any DNS for my service. I have created service using kubectl commands . Suppose I have created a service for nginx pod which is accessible at port 31220. I acccess it using curl <node1>:31220 and curl node2:31220, then how can we specify 'eureka.serviceUrl.default' in this case ?

Comment: Every service in Kubernetes gets a DNS (assuming) your cluster is configured correctly. The format is like this `<service-name>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local` so it depends on the name of your eureka-server service name.

Comment: Hi Rico, Thanks for your answer. I checked the zuul service which I had deployed from netflix. There is a zuul-test.properties file. I had made changes as per your suggestion. But I guess in order to bring these changes into effect, zuul needs to be restarted. I searched but was'nt able to find a suitable solution for this. Can you tell me how can we restart zuul service in this cluster ?